# How to select a specific object based on other object from the same parent using uiautomator

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-uiautomator

Let's say you need to test youtube. You have a list of videos, and each video has a Name, duration, uploader.

Now, let's say in this list, you can have several videos and some of them have the same name, but different uploaders.

I need to check if the video with name "X" and uploader "Y" is on the list (considering that the same uploader could have uploaded more than one video with the same name) and I have no idea how to make it work.

This is the hierarchy I have:

- (0)RelativeLayout (where the first element of the list starts)

  - (0)LinearLayout

    - (1)LinearLayout

      - (0)TestView (where the name of the video is)
      - (1)LinearLayout

        - (1)LinearLayout

          - ()TextView (where the uploader is)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're still struggling on this, but anyway...

You can use [`public UiSelector childSelector (UiSelector selector)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiSelector.html#childSelector(android.support.test.uiautomator.UiSelector))

> Adds a child UiSelector criteria to this selector. Use this selector to narrow the search scope to child widgets under a specific parent widget.

For instance, you can do something like this (I haven't tested it):

```
UiSelector videoXFromY = new UiSelector().text("X").childSelector(new UiSelector().text("Y");
```